# Using <object> to embed svg but doesn't show anything

Tags: vue.js, svg

I was trying to use  to embed the svg picture but it does not show anything. I looked at some other threads and it was suggested to add type="image/svg+xml", however, it did not solve the issue. When I am trying to look at the DOM for some reason it seems to create an endless loop. I attached the picture

This is the compononent

```
<template>

    <div class="logo">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="logo.svg">

        </object>
    </div>

</template>
```

This is the app.vue

````
template>
  <div id="app">
      <Demo></Demo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Demo from './components/Demo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Demo
  }
}
</script>
```[![Snapshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ipO.png
````

Comment: You probably have wrong path inside your "data" attribute. You can try this by adding the svg inside an <img>-tag and seeing if that shows up. If the <img> won't show up  either it's most likely the path that's wrong.

Comment: As far as the path, when I use <img src=""> it works and I can see the SVG. However, I am trying to use <object> so I am able to interact with <path> inside of my svg

Answer (score 2):

This happen because *vue-loader* doesn’t recognize paths in just any attribute. By default just recognize these ones: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls

So, there are 3 possible solutions

Note: If you are not using *eslint* as linter you could remove *eslint* comments

1: **Bind the route to your image**

First add the next variable to your data in the component

```
data() {
    return {
      // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
      mySvg: require('../assets/logo.svg'),
    };
  },
```

Next modify your template

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" :data="mySvg">
```

**2: Add *vue-loader* rule**

If you don't want to have to bind every svg image, you could add a rule to *vue-loader* in order to say how to handle *data* attribute in a *object*

Go to your *webpack* config file, if you created the project using *vue-cli* 3.x you have to create a `vue.config.js` file in the root (same level that *package.json*)

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        options.transformAssetUrls = {
          object: 'data',
        };

        return options;
      });
  },
};
```

if you want to check that the config was added, execute `vue inspect > webpack.config` and expect see something like this (inside `webpack.config`):

```
    {
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          ...
          transformAssetUrls: {
            object: 'data'
          }
        }
      }
```

More info: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack

**3: Replace default loader and use svg as vue components**

Other option is use *vue-svg-loader*. This loader inlines the SVGs which enables you to modify them using css. Also optimize your files with *SVGO*

See more: https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/#vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking that you don't have a CSS rule hiding object tags. Otherwise it seems correct. You probably need to check the path and make sure you can reach your image. I assume your filename is a dummy, but try to use an absolute path. And make sure you can hit the path and see the image in your browser.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ipO.png you can take a look at the picture. For some reason, it creates an infinite loop inside of my code. But when I just use <img src="", it renders my picture

Comment: You see I still think there is something with the path, or more precisely with what the router (either server side, or javascript router if you have one) is doing. It looks like the router "thinks" that "logo.svg" is the page you are on, instead of the image, and this is why it is nested infinitely. The fact that it works makes me think it is more likely a javascript router doing this. Do you have a codepen you can share? It would be easier, because I think the problem is somewhere else.